# Apache Airflow or Apache Beam for data processing and job scheduling

Tags: pandas, airflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to give useful information but I am far from being a data engineer.

I am currently using the python library pandas to execute a long series of transformation to my data which has a lot of inputs (currently CSV and excel files). The outputs are several excel files. I would like to be able to execute scheduled monitored batch jobs with parallel computation (I mean not as sequential as what I'm doing with pandas), once a month.

I don't really know Beam or Airflow, I quickly read through the docs and it seems that both can achieve that. Which one should I use ?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

The other answers are quite technical and hard to understand. I was in your position before so I'll explain in *simple terms*.

**Airflow** can do *anything*. It has `BashOperator` and `PythonOperator` which means it can run any bash script or any Python script.
It is a way to organize (setup complicated data pipeline DAGs), schedule, monitor, trigger re-runs of data pipelines, in a easy-to-view and use UI.
Also, it is easy to setup and everything is in familiar Python code.
Doing pipelines in an organized manner (i.e using Airflow) means you don't waste time debugging a mess of data processing (`cron`) scripts all over the place.
Nowadays (roughly year 2020 onwards), we call it an **orchestration** tool.

**Apache Beam** is a wrapper for the many data processing frameworks (Spark, Flink etc.) out there.
The intent is so you just learn Beam and can run on multiple backends (Beam runners).
If you are familiar with Keras and TensorFlow/Theano/Torch, the relationship between Keras and its backends is similar to the relationship between Beam and its data processing backends.

Google Cloud Platform's Cloud Dataflow is one backend for running Beam on.
They call it the [Dataflow runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/dataflow/).

GCP's offering, **Cloud Composer**, is a **managed Airflow implementation** as a service, running in a Kubernetes cluster in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE).

So you can either:

- manual Airflow implementation, doing data processing on the instance itself (if your data is small (or your instance is powerful enough), you can process data on the machine running Airflow. This is why many are confused if Airflow can process data or not)
- manual Airflow implementation calling Beam jobs
- Cloud Composer (managed Airflow as a service) calling jobs in Cloud Dataflow
- Cloud Composer running data processing containers in Composer's Kubernetes cluster environment itself, using Airflow's `KubernetesPodOperator (KPO)`
- Cloud Composer running data processing containers in Composer's Kubernetes cluster environment with Airflow's `KPO`, but this time in a better **isolated** fashion by creating a new node-pool and specifying that the `KPO` pods are to be run in the new node-pool

**My personal experience**:
Airflow is lightweight and not difficult to learn (easy to implement), you should use it for your data pipelines whenever possible.
Also, since many companies are looking for experience using Airflow, if you're looking to be a data engineer you should probably learn it
Also, managed Airflow (I've only used GCP's Composer so far) is much more convenient than running Airflow yourself, and managing the airflow `webserver` and `scheduler` processes.

Comment: Regarding the first option, airflow "calls" beam and then what? Where do the pipelines actually run? Do I need to also setup a spark cluster or something and connect it to airflow?

Comment: yes, it calls a job in Beam, and your Beam job could be running Spark, Flink etc, or a job in Cloud Dataflow using the Dataflow runner in Beam. Pipelines is a vague term and i try to avoid it. The scheduling occurs in Airflow, and the data processing occurs in a separate cluster. You could probably have 1 Airflow task to start a data processing cluster (Spark/Flink), 1 Airflow task to call the job using Beam, and then another Airflow task to tear down the cluster. And yes you need to link your data processing cluster to Airflow.

Answer (score 81):

Apache Airflow and Apache Beam look quite similar on the surface. Both of them allow you to organise a set of steps that process your data and both ensure the steps run in the right order and have their dependencies satisfied. Both allow you to visualise the steps and dependencies as a directed acyclic graph (DAG) in a GUI.

But when you dig a bit deeper there are big differences in what they do and the programming models they support.

Airflow is a task management system. The nodes of the DAG are tasks and Airflow makes sure to run them in the proper order, making sure one task only starts once its dependency tasks have finished. Dependent tasks don't run at the same time but only one after another. Independent tasks can run concurrently.

Beam is a dataflow engine. The nodes of the DAG form a (possibly branching) pipeline. All the nodes in the DAG are active at the same time, and they pass data elements from one to the next, each doing some processing on it.

The two have some overlapping use cases but there are a lot of things only one of the two can do well.

Airflow manages tasks, which depend on one another. While this dependency can consist of one task passing data to the next one, that is not a requirement. In fact Airflow doesn't even care what the tasks do, it just needs to start them and see if they finished or failed. If tasks need to pass data to one another you need to co-ordinate that yourself, telling each task where to read and write its data, e.g. a local file path or a web service somewhere. Tasks can consist of Python code but they can also be any external program or a web service call.

In Beam, your step definitions are tightly integrated with the engine. You define the steps in a supported programming language and they run inside a Beam process. Handling the computation in an external process would be difficult if possible at all*, and is certainly not the way Beam is supposed to be used. Your steps only need to worry about the computation they're performing, not about storing or transferring the data. Transferring the data between different steps is handled entirely by the framework.

In Airflow, if your tasks process data, a single task invocation typically does some transformation on the entire dataset. In Beam, the data processing is part of the core interfaces so it can't really do anything else. An invocation of a Beam step typically handles a single or a few data elements and not the full dataset. Because of this Beam also supports unbounded length datasets, which is not something Airflow can natively cope with.

Another difference is that Airflow is a framework by itself, but Beam is actually an abstraction layer. Beam pipelines can run on Apache Spark, Apache Flink, Google Cloud Dataflow and others. All of these support a more or less similar programming model. Google has also cloudified Airflow into a service as Google Cloud Compose by the way.

*Apache Spark's support for Python is actually implemented by running a full Python interpreter in a subprocess, but this is implemented at the framework level.

Comment: `only starts once its dependency tasks have finished` so it should not be used for streaming?

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax indeed. Streaming doesn't even make much sense in the Airflow programming model. Quoting from the Airflow docs frontpage: "Airflow **is not** a data streaming solution." https://airflow.apache.org/

Comment: what's the true difference, it looks like all you mentioned features about airflow can also be achieved in the dataflow model. If beam can not do that, it's only because they haven't implemented that functionality.

Answer (score 22):

[Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/) is not a data processing engine.

> Airflow is a platform to programmatically author, schedule, and
>   monitor workflows.

[Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) is a fully-managed service on Google Cloud that can be used for data processing. You can write your Dataflow code and then use Airflow to schedule and monitor Dataflow job. Airflow also allows you to retry your job if it fails (number of retries is configurable). You can also configure in Airflow if you want to send alerts on Slack or email, if your Dataflow pipeline fails.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same as you with airflow, and I've got very good results. I am not very sure about the following: Beam is machine learning focused and airflow is for anything you want.
Finally you can create a hive with kubernetes +airflow.